# Tag synonym/merge suggestion

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

We have a popular tag for [unobtrusive-validation](/questions/tagged/unobtrusive-validation).

I noticed we also have a less popular tag called [validate-unobtrusive](/questions/tagged/validate-unobtrusive).

I believe that the second tag should be merged into [unobtrusive-validation](/questions/tagged/unobtrusive-validation) and I don't have the rep to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only 13 questions.

Just edit them, replacing the [validate-unobtrusive](/questions/tagged/validate-unobtrusive) tag with the other, and let the removed tag die naturally.

Comment: Really? That's better than somebody simply doing a merge?  I'm not familiar with merge process so that's not a snarky question.  Also, won't that drive all those old questions back to the top?

Comment: With only 13 questions it's clearly not that often confused; in this case it's easy to fix those few questions.

Comment: ok, got half... and you must have done the others.

Comment: @Sparky: Exactly. :) I started at the bottom, you came in from the top.